# Can I differentiate between single and double clicks on the system tray icon?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-shell, system-tray, trayicon

I create my system tray icon using `Shell_NotifyIcon` and then trap its `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` notifications for when a user double-clicks the icon (I use it show a dialog window.) I also trap `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` notifications to show the context menu.

Now I'm thinking that it would be nice to show a context menu after a single left click. But how do I do that?

If I trap `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and show my context menu it works fine. But then when someone double-clicks the icon, it first shows my context menu and then displays the dialog window. So I'm not sure how to overcome this?

**EDIT:** Here's my code:

```
NOTIFYICONDATA nid;
memset(&nid, 0, sizeof(nid));
nid.cbSize = sizeof(nid);
nid.hWnd = this->GetSafeHwnd();
nid.uID = TRAY_ICON_ID1;
nid.uFlags = NIF_ICON;
nid.uCallbackMessage = TRAY_NOTIFICATION_ID1;
nid.hIcon = ghIcon;

Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &nid);
```

and then:

```
ON_MESSAGE(TRAY_NOTIFICATION_ID1, OnTrayIconNotifications)

LRESULT OnTrayIconNotifications(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UINT uID = (UINT)wParam;
    UINT uMouseMsg = (UINT)lParam;

    if(uID == TRAY_ICON_ID1)
    {
        switch(uMouseMsg)
        {
        case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
            {
                //Show context menu
                //...
                int nChosenCmd = TrackPopupMenu(hMenu, 
                    TPM_RIGHTALIGN | TPM_TOPALIGN |
                    TPM_LEFTBUTTON | TPM_VERPOSANIMATION | 
                    TPM_HORNEGANIMATION | TPM_RETURNCMD,
                    x, y, 0, 
                    this->GetSafeHwnd(), NULL);
            }
            break;

        case WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
            {
                //Show dialog window
                CDialogBasedClass dlg(this);
                dlg.DoModal();
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _'Can I differentiate between single and double clicks on the system tray icon?'_ Without knowing exactly how, I'd suspect **YES**, it's distinguishable, because I frequently notice different behavior of applications when I'm doing so.

Comment: There's no code here. We don't know how you manage your notification icon. Please show code. Also, there is no such thing as a tray icon. It is a notification icon.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: `Shell_NotifyIcon` adds the icon, I then trap notifications with `uCallbackMessage` in the main window.

Comment: Sigh. If you won't show code we can only guess at what it is. You won't show the code so we don't know what version of notification icon you ask for. In order to show your code you would need to make some effort. Is it really that hard?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: OK, I see your point. I'm using `NOTIFYICONDATAW` that is 952 bytes long. Does it make a difference for the double-click behavior?

Comment: It's up to you whether or not you show the code

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: OK. Can you now please explain why you made me post it?

Comment: Like I said, I wanted to know which version of the notification icon you were using. Now I can see that you set `uVersion` to 0 and use the Win95 version.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: And you couldn't just ask me that? Plus what connection does it have to what I was asking?

Comment: Often people say one thing but the code says another. It's not hard to add code.

Comment: Anyway, the only way to do it is the way that Jon says. You should accept that answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you will have to get smart about it.

In your `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` click handler, [set a timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that expires after the system's [double click time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646258%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has elapsed. In your `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLICK` handler check if that timer is active and if it is, cancel it.

If the timer expires that means the user clicked your icon but did not go ahead and double-click it; that means it's time to show the context menu.

Comment: Well, it's a solution. I'll need to try it.

Answer (score 1):

Show context menu on `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` or `WM_CONTEXTMENU`. Regarding left button single and double click, correct design requires double-click handler as continuation of single click. For example, in Windows Explorer single click selects a file, and double click opens it. Single click handler always works before double click handler, and this should look natural. In your case I would show a menu on right click, and dialog on left click.

Solutions based on timers and delays create buggy and unreliable code.

Comment: Can you explain why "Solutions based on timers and delays create buggy and unreliable code"? Double-click itself is based on a timer.

Comment: You need to delay single-click handler, I don't think that users like this. Regarding timer solutions - don't expect high precision, Windows is not real-time system. Double-click itself is not reliable. But technically this is possible.

Comment: BTW, it was not my intention to debate with another answers, they were posted later.

Comment: In my testing `GetTickCount` can reliably produce a precision of down to 10ms. That is way less than the double-click precision.

Comment: "In my testing". Have you tested on every system? There are plenty of systems with worse resolution than that? Try not to design software based on your own imprecise experiments.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I tested `GetTickCount` on some very old and slow machines running XP and 10 ms precision was not an issue. (It didn't go lower though.)

Comment: Even some ancient CPU running at 500MHz (if you can still find one) would be able to do 10,000+ operations per 10 ms.