# Differentiate between single and double click in python

Tags: python, pywin32, win32gui

I'm working on a well-known [SysTrayIcon](http://www.brunningonline.net/simon/blog/archives/SysTrayIcon.py.html) example, and need to handle both single click and double click.

```
def notify(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
    if lparam==win32con.WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        self.execute_menu_option(self.default_menu_index + self.FIRST_ID)
    elif lparam==win32con.WM_RBUTTONUP:
        self.show_menu()
    elif lparam==win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP:
        pass
    return True
```

I know that this involves creating a timer:

- Qt has QTimer.singleShot
  ([example](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Distinguishing%20between%20click%20and%20double%20click))
- PySide has QtCore.QTimer
  ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444152/differentiate-single-click-from-double-click-in-pyside))
- wx has wx.timer
  ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991091/how-to-distinguish-the-double-click-and-single-click-of-mouse-in-wxpython))

But what is the best way to accomplish it in "pure" python (that is ctypes/pywin32 only, without qt, wx or gtk) ? Create a thread by myself? Or start a some kind of a windows timer that would generate WM_TIMER message for me when necessary?

PS I've found a proper way to ask windows about the user's preference concerning double click time [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919117/can-i-differentiate-between-single-and-double-clicks-on-the-system-tray-icon).

PPS I've also read an opinion of how bad it is to handle both single and double click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23919308/237105).

Comment: Have clicking set a flag and start a countdown timer, then have the countdown timer clear the flag when it completes, and if a click happens while the flag is on, it's a double-click?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 That's right. In my question I linked three implementations that do exactly what you suggest. The question is which is a proper way to accomplish it without extra libs: create a separate thread or use some windows api for timer.

Comment: Does pywin32 not have some sort of event timer like Tkinter's `after()`?

Comment: [`timer`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/timer.html), for example.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. pywin32 docs are way nonstraightforward. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pywin32`'s [`timer` module](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/timer.html). Set a double-click flag and start the timer in the click callback, and clear the double-click flag in the timer callback, and kill the timer in the click callback after detecting a double-click.

To start a timer:

```
timer_id = set_timer(delay_period, callback)
```

To stop the timer:

```
kill_timer(timer_id)
```